# Is this the way to make sure a FileField associated to a model will be deleted?

Tags: django, django-file-upload

When I delete a model's instance that has a FileField, the actual file is left in my MEDIA_ROOT folder. To counter this, I'm listening for the post_delete signal, and doing this:

```
def delete_actual_file(sender,**kwargs):
  import os
  instance = kwargs.get("instance")
  os.unlink(instance.file.path)

post_delete.connect(delete_actual_file,sender=ModelWithFileField)
```

It seems to work ok, but I'm not sure if it's best practice to do it like this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Django are you using? The [behaviour changed in Django 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#deleting-a-model-doesn-t-delete-associated-files). The docs you might want are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FieldFile.delete) and you can hook that into your signal, but it'd have to become a pre-delete action, I imagine.

Comment: I'm using 1.3. Why should it become a pre-delete action?

Comment: Because, off the top of my head / without looking at the code, I would't want to bet on that row still being in the DB post_delete. But I could be wrong.

Comment: It's true, maybe it won't be in the db, but you still have access to the instance in the kwargs, and it contains valid data. The code I posted above works, but I wasn't sure about my approach to deletion.

Comment: If it works, that's great. I guess the file handle will still be valid in the instance that's being passed around, but I wasn't sure when that was being evaluated (lazily or not). Glad it's working for you.